# JPA not creating database entry for many to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have these 2 classes (shortened):

```
@Entity
public class ClanPlayer {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "players")
    private List<PhoenixPermission> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    public ClanPlayer() {}

    public List<PhoenixPermission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<PhoenixPermission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public void addPermission(PhoenixPermission permission) {
        EntityManager em = EMUtils.getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        permissions.add(permission);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class PhoenixPermission {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    private int id;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PLAYER_PERMISSION")
    private List<ClanPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();

    public PhoenixPermission() {}

    public List<ClanPlayer> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(List<ClanPlayer> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

Now, while calling the `addPermission` method with a PhoenixPermission-Entity object, the ArrayList 'permissions' is updated, but there is no new tuple in the database of the 'PLAYER_PERMISSION' table.

The debug log doesn't show any insert queries for this table.
All other Entity Manager operations are working fine.
I assume there is something wrong with my annotations, but I am not sure about.
Any ideas?

Comment: You should learn about the concept of the owning side of a relation: it's the one responsible for maintaining the relation so only if the owning side is changed will the database be updated. In your case the owning side is `PhoenixPermission .players` so you need to add a new player to get the update. (`ClanPlayer.permissions` has `mappedBy = "players"` in its `@ManyToMany` - that's how you can tell it is _not_ the owning side but `players` is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
I just had to update both objects. Here is the updated `addPermission` method:

```
public void addPermission(PhoenixPermission permission) {
    EntityManager em = EMUtils.getEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    permissions.add(permission);
    permission.getPlayers().add(this);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```